# Android Listview Questions

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the following class in my program:

```
public class RZoom extends Activity {
private ArrayList<FItem> m_FItems;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fchooser);

    TextView tvName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitleShow);

    m_fItems = ((ArrayList<FItem>)this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("fItems"));
    tvName.setText(this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("RName"));

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    FItemAdapter adapter = new FItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row, m_FItems);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

This class displays a custom Listview and everything works fine. My questions are:

1. How do I capture an item click on the Listview? All the examples I've seen seem to inherit ListActivity instead of Activity, like I'm doing.
2. Is there a way to iterate through the items in the listview and set the background color of the item to Red, depending on the actual item? (In other words, I want to programmically highlight an item depending on the actual item)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. lv.setOnItemClickListener()
2. Override FItemAdapter's getView() to change colors depending on the item/position

Answer (score 0):

1. For your first question you need to grab the ListView from its ID, as you are inheriting from Activity and not from ListActivity:

   ```
   ListView lv_GetViewList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
   lv_GetViewList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
      {
         // Your Code here
      }
   });
   ```

2 . You can override the getView() function and then grab the desired control of the row depending upon the conditions you want to use for a particular Control or all of the controls, say, a TextView. And you can set its background color:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
   TextView tv_Text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myRowTextView);
   if(tv_Text != null)
   {
        tv_Text.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   }
   return v;
}
```